# How can I capture volume button events in Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

From my understanding, in Cordova you can capture volume button events using `document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);` and `document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);`

These allows you to cancel the default behaviour of the event, and 'take over' the volume buttons for your own purpose (which is what I need).

The problem I have is that this doesn't work when an InAppBrowser window is open. Presumably the user must be focused on the main Cordova window to receive these events.

Is there a possible workaround to this?

Comment: You could inject some JS into the inAppBrowser window that captures the event then use a callback